# Need free backup software that stays within my country

Tags: windows, open-source, osx, backup

I need to backup my computer files to another computer or device that is in the same country as I am. Would prefer an open-source or free option for the backups.

This would need to work for multiple computers using both Mac and Windows.

Comment: If you want to ensure data geographical position, then don't use someone's else computer to backup, that is, stay away from anything that says "cloud". Just use an external hard drive and move it to another location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how many files and folders need backing up, your might be best using a external hard drive with a calendar reminder every month to backup the files. This would be the simplest and cheapest option for you and could work on all platforms.

You could also try a local IT provider and ask if the data is stored in the same country, but this option wouldn't be free but would be well managed.

Answer (score 2):

There's always Resilio Sync - the free tier already grants enough possibilities and kan keep the files on your LAN if you so desire.

If you really want to stay open source, try Syncthing - it is CLI only but as far as I can tell it has some GUI wrappers you can download along. I am actually planning on moving to it from Resilio.

The method is generally that you set up a folder to sync, and then you can get a key which then can be fed to a different PC on your LAN (with a drive attached for backup or whatever) so it will make copy of the folder there. Mostly seamless although sometimes it locks up a file or two for longer than it should - I tend to turn it off whenever I work in Visual Studio for example.